# Interfacing issue LPC1769 and MPU6050

Tags: c, embedded, arm, gyroscope, lpc

I'm trying to interface LPC1769 and MPU6050 And i am using **mcb1700.code.bundle.lpc1769.lpcxpresso** libraries. And I'm using LpcXpresso as IDE.

As specified in the MPU6050 datasheet I coded for the read sequence, it's working first time only, if i try to read second time, it returns zero values. ( i.e., it works only once after the reset )

I tried with many possible ways, No results So please give me some solution to fix this Issue.

**Edited..**
Code I've shown below. Both read and burstRead code working only once

i2c.c

```
    #include "lpc17xx.h"
    #include "type.h"
    #include "i2c.h"

    volatile uint32_t I2CMasterState[I2C_PORT_NUM] = {I2C_IDLE,I2C_IDLE,I2C_IDLE};
    volatile uint32_t timeout[I2C_PORT_NUM] = {0, 0, 0};

    volatile uint8_t I2CMasterBuffer[I2C_PORT_NUM][BUFSIZE];
    volatile uint8_t I2CSlaveBuffer[I2C_PORT_NUM][BUFSIZE];
    volatile uint32_t I2CCount[I2C_PORT_NUM] = {0, 0, 0};
    volatile uint32_t I2CReadLength[I2C_PORT_NUM];
    volatile uint32_t I2CWriteLength[I2C_PORT_NUM];

    volatile uint32_t RdIndex0 = 0, RdIndex1 = 0, RdIndex2 = 0;
    volatile uint32_t WrIndex0 = 0, WrIndex1 = 0, WrIndex2 = 0;

    /* 
    From device to device, the I2C communication protocol may vary, 
    in the example below, the protocol uses repeated start to read data from or 
    write to the device:
    For master read: the sequence is: STA,Addr(W),offset,RE-STA,Addr(r),data...STO 
    for master write: the sequence is: STA,Addr(W),offset,RE-STA,Addr(w),data...STO
    Thus, in state 8, the address is always WRITE. in state 10, the address could 
    be READ or WRITE depending on the I2C command.
    */   

    /*****************************************************************************
    ** Function name:       I2C_IRQHandler
    **
    ** Descriptions:        I2C interrupt handler, deal with master mode only.
    **
    ** parameters:          None
    ** Returned value:      None
    ** 
    *****************************************************************************/
    void I2C0_IRQHandler(void) 
    {
      uint8_t StatValue;

      timeout[0] = 0;
      /* this handler deals with master read and master write only */
      StatValue = LPC_I2C0->STAT;
      switch ( StatValue )
      {
        case 0x08:          /* A Start condition is issued. */
        WrIndex0 = 0;
        LPC_I2C0->DAT = I2CMasterBuffer[0][WrIndex0++];
        LPC_I2C0->CONCLR = (I2CONCLR_SIC | I2CONCLR_STAC);
        break;

        case 0x10:          /* A repeated started is issued */
        RdIndex0 = 0;
        /* Send SLA with R bit set, */
        LPC_I2C0->DAT = I2CMasterBuffer[0][WrIndex0++];
        LPC_I2C0->CONCLR = (I2CONCLR_SIC | I2CONCLR_STAC);
        break;

        case 0x18:          /* Regardless, it's a ACK */
        if ( I2CWriteLength[0] == 1 )
        {
          LPC_I2C0->CONSET = I2CONSET_STO;      /* Set Stop flag */
          I2CMasterState[0] = I2C_NO_DATA;
        }
        else
        {
          LPC_I2C0->DAT = I2CMasterBuffer[0][WrIndex0++];
        }
        LPC_I2C0->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;
        break;

        case 0x28:  /* Data byte has been transmitted, regardless ACK or NACK */
        if ( WrIndex0 < I2CWriteLength[0] )
        {   
          LPC_I2C0->DAT = I2CMasterBuffer[0][WrIndex0++]; /* this should be the last one */
        }
        else
        {
          if ( I2CReadLength[0] != 0 )
          {
            LPC_I2C0->CONSET = I2CONSET_STA;    /* Set Repeated-start flag */
          }
          else
          {
            LPC_I2C0->CONSET = I2CONSET_STO;      /* Set Stop flag */
            I2CMasterState[0] = I2C_OK;
          }
        }
        LPC_I2C0->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;
        break;

        case 0x30:
        LPC_I2C0->CONSET = I2CONSET_STO;      /* Set Stop flag */
        I2CMasterState[0] = I2C_NACK_ON_DATA;
        LPC_I2C0->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;
        break;

        case 0x40:  /* Master Receive, SLA_R has been sent */
        if ( (RdIndex0 + 1) < I2CReadLength[0] )
        {
          /* Will go to State 0x50 */
          LPC_I2C0->CONSET = I2CONSET_AA;   /* assert ACK after data is received */
        }
        else
        {
          /* Will go to State 0x58 */
          LPC_I2C0->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_AAC;  /* assert NACK after data is received */
        }
        LPC_I2C0->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;
        break;

        case 0x50:  /* Data byte has been received, regardless following ACK or NACK */
        I2CSlaveBuffer[0][RdIndex0++] = LPC_I2C0->DAT;
        if ( (RdIndex0 + 1) < I2CReadLength[0] )
        {   
          LPC_I2C0->CONSET = I2CONSET_AA;   /* assert ACK after data is received */
        }
        else
        {
          LPC_I2C0->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_AAC;  /* assert NACK on last byte */
        }
        LPC_I2C0->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;
        break;

        case 0x58:
        I2CSlaveBuffer[0][RdIndex0++] = LPC_I2C0->DAT;
        I2CMasterState[0] = I2C_OK;
        LPC_I2C0->CONSET = I2CONSET_STO;    /* Set Stop flag */ 
        LPC_I2C0->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;    /* Clear SI flag */
        break;

        case 0x20:      /* regardless, it's a NACK */
        case 0x48:
        LPC_I2C0->CONSET = I2CONSET_STO;      /* Set Stop flag */
        I2CMasterState[0] = I2C_NACK_ON_ADDRESS;
        LPC_I2C0->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;
        break;

        case 0x38:      /* Arbitration lost, in this example, we don't
                        deal with multiple master situation */
        default:
        I2CMasterState[0] = I2C_ARBITRATION_LOST;
        LPC_I2C0->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;    
        break;
      }
      return;
    }

    /*****************************************************************************
    ** Function name:       I2C_IRQHandler
    **
    ** Descriptions:        I2C interrupt handler, deal with master mode only.
    **
    ** parameters:          None
    ** Returned value:      None
    ** 
    *****************************************************************************/
    void I2C1_IRQHandler(void) 
    {
      uint8_t StatValue;

      timeout[1] = 0;
      /* this handler deals with master read and master write only */
      StatValue = LPC_I2C1->STAT;
      switch ( StatValue )
      {
        case 0x08:          /* A Start condition is issued. */
        WrIndex1 = 0;
        LPC_I2C1->DAT = I2CMasterBuffer[1][WrIndex1++];
        LPC_I2C1->CONCLR = (I2CONCLR_SIC | I2CONCLR_STAC);
        break;

        case 0x10:          /* A repeated started is issued */
        RdIndex1 = 0;
        /* Send SLA with R bit set, */
        LPC_I2C1->DAT = I2CMasterBuffer[1][WrIndex1++];
        LPC_I2C1->CONCLR = (I2CONCLR_SIC | I2CONCLR_STAC);
        break;

        case 0x18:          /* Regardless, it's a ACK */
        if ( I2CWriteLength[1] == 1 )
        {
          LPC_I2C1->CONSET = I2CONSET_STO;      /* Set Stop flag */
          I2CMasterState[1] = I2C_NO_DATA;
        }
        else
        {
          LPC_I2C1->DAT = I2CMasterBuffer[1][WrIndex1++];
        }
        LPC_I2C1->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;
        break;

        case 0x28:  /* Data byte has been transmitted, regardless ACK or NACK */
        if ( WrIndex1 < I2CWriteLength[1] )
        {   
          LPC_I2C1->DAT = I2CMasterBuffer[1][WrIndex1++]; /* this should be the last one */
        }
        else
        {
          if ( I2CReadLength[1] != 0 )
          {
            LPC_I2C1->CONSET = I2CONSET_STA;    /* Set Repeated-start flag */
          }
          else
          {
            LPC_I2C1->CONSET = I2CONSET_STO;      /* Set Stop flag */
            I2CMasterState[1] = I2C_OK;
          }
        }
        LPC_I2C1->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;
        break;

        case 0x30:
        LPC_I2C1->CONSET = I2CONSET_STO;      /* Set Stop flag */
        I2CMasterState[1] = I2C_NACK_ON_DATA;
        LPC_I2C1->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;
        break;

        case 0x40:  /* Master Receive, SLA_R has been sent */
        if ( (RdIndex1 + 1) < I2CReadLength[1] )
        {
          /* Will go to State 0x50 */
          LPC_I2C1->CONSET = I2CONSET_AA;   /* assert ACK after data is received */
        }
        else
        {
          /* Will go to State 0x58 */
          LPC_I2C1->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_AAC;  /* assert NACK after data is received */
        }
        LPC_I2C1->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;
        break;

        case 0x50:  /* Data byte has been received, regardless following ACK or NACK */
        I2CSlaveBuffer[1][RdIndex1++] = LPC_I2C1->DAT;
        if ( (RdIndex1 + 1) < I2CReadLength[1] )
        {   
          LPC_I2C1->CONSET = I2CONSET_AA;   /* assert ACK after data is received */
        }
        else
        {
          LPC_I2C1->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_AAC;  /* assert NACK on last byte */
        }
        LPC_I2C1->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;
        break;

        case 0x58:
        I2CSlaveBuffer[1][RdIndex1++] = LPC_I2C1->DAT;
        I2CMasterState[1] = I2C_OK;
        LPC_I2C1->CONSET = I2CONSET_STO;    /* Set Stop flag */ 
        LPC_I2C1->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;    /* Clear SI flag */
        break;

        case 0x20:      /* regardless, it's a NACK */
        case 0x48:
        LPC_I2C1->CONSET = I2CONSET_STO;      /* Set Stop flag */
        I2CMasterState[1] = I2C_NACK_ON_ADDRESS;
        LPC_I2C1->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;
        break;

        case 0x38:      /* Arbitration lost, in this example, we don't
                        deal with multiple master situation */
        default:
        I2CMasterState[1] = I2C_ARBITRATION_LOST;
        LPC_I2C1->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;    
        break;
      }
      return;
    }

    /*****************************************************************************
    ** Function name:       I2C_IRQHandler
    **
    ** Descriptions:        I2C interrupt handler, deal with master mode only.
    **
    ** parameters:          None
    ** Returned value:      None
    ** 
    *****************************************************************************/
    void I2C2_IRQHandler(void) 
    {
      uint8_t StatValue;

      timeout[2] = 0;
      /* this handler deals with master read and master write only */
      StatValue = LPC_I2C2->STAT;
      switch ( StatValue )
      {
        case 0x08:          /* A Start condition is issued. */
        WrIndex2 = 0;
        LPC_I2C2->DAT = I2CMasterBuffer[2][WrIndex2++];
        LPC_I2C2->CONCLR = (I2CONCLR_SIC | I2CONCLR_STAC);
        break;

        case 0x10:          /* A repeated started is issued */
        RdIndex2 = 0;
        /* Send SLA with R bit set, */
        LPC_I2C2->DAT = I2CMasterBuffer[2][WrIndex2++];
        LPC_I2C2->CONCLR = (I2CONCLR_SIC | I2CONCLR_STAC);
        break;

        case 0x18:          /* Regardless, it's a ACK */
        if ( I2CWriteLength[2] == 1 )
        {
          LPC_I2C2->CONSET = I2CONSET_STO;      /* Set Stop flag */
          I2CMasterState[2] = I2C_NO_DATA;
        }
        else
        {
          LPC_I2C2->DAT = I2CMasterBuffer[2][WrIndex2++];
        }
        LPC_I2C2->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;
        break;

        case 0x28:  /* Data byte has been transmitted, regardless ACK or NACK */
        if ( WrIndex2 < I2CWriteLength[2] )
        {   
          LPC_I2C2->DAT = I2CMasterBuffer[2][WrIndex2++]; /* this should be the last one */
        }
        else
        {
          if ( I2CReadLength[2] != 0 )
          {
            LPC_I2C2->CONSET = I2CONSET_STA;    /* Set Repeated-start flag */
          }
          else
          {
            LPC_I2C2->CONSET = I2CONSET_STO;      /* Set Stop flag */
            I2CMasterState[2] = I2C_OK;
          }
        }
        LPC_I2C2->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;
        break;

        case 0x30:
        LPC_I2C2->CONSET = I2CONSET_STO;      /* Set Stop flag */
        I2CMasterState[2] = I2C_NACK_ON_DATA;
        LPC_I2C2->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;
        break;

        case 0x40:  /* Master Receive, SLA_R has been sent */
        if ( (RdIndex2 + 1) < I2CReadLength[2] )
        {
          /* Will go to State 0x50 */
          LPC_I2C2->CONSET = I2CONSET_AA;   /* assert ACK after data is received */
        }
        else
        {
          /* Will go to State 0x58 */
          LPC_I2C2->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_AAC;  /* assert NACK after data is received */
        }
        LPC_I2C2->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;
        break;

        case 0x50:  /* Data byte has been received, regardless following ACK or NACK */
        I2CSlaveBuffer[2][RdIndex2++] = LPC_I2C2->DAT;
        if ( (RdIndex2 + 1) < I2CReadLength[2] )
        {   
          LPC_I2C2->CONSET = I2CONSET_AA;   /* assert ACK after data is received */
        }
        else
        {
          LPC_I2C2->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_AAC;  /* assert NACK on last byte */
        }
        LPC_I2C2->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;
        break;

        case 0x58:
        I2CSlaveBuffer[2][RdIndex2++] = LPC_I2C2->DAT;
        I2CMasterState[2] = I2C_OK;
        LPC_I2C2->CONSET = I2CONSET_STO;    /* Set Stop flag */ 
        LPC_I2C2->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;    /* Clear SI flag */
        break;

        case 0x20:      /* regardless, it's a NACK */
        case 0x48:
        LPC_I2C2->CONSET = I2CONSET_STO;      /* Set Stop flag */
        I2CMasterState[2] = I2C_NACK_ON_ADDRESS;
        LPC_I2C2->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;
        break;

        case 0x38:      /* Arbitration lost, in this example, we don't
                        deal with multiple master situation */
        default:
        I2CMasterState[2] = I2C_ARBITRATION_LOST;
        LPC_I2C2->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;    
        break;
      }
      return;
    }

    /*****************************************************************************
    ** Function name:       I2CStart
    **
    ** Descriptions:        Create I2C start condition, a timeout
    **              value is set if the I2C never gets started,
    **              and timed out. It's a fatal error. 
    **
    ** parameters:          None
    ** Returned value:      true or false, return false if timed out
    ** 
    *****************************************************************************/
    uint32_t I2CStart( uint32_t portNum )
    {
      uint32_t retVal = FALSE;

      timeout[portNum] = 0;
      /*--- Issue a start condition ---*/
      LPC_I2C[portNum]->CONSET = I2CONSET_STA;  /* Set Start flag */

      /*--- Wait until START transmitted ---*/
      while( 1 )
      {
        if ( I2CMasterState[portNum] == I2C_STARTED )
        {
          retVal = TRUE;
          break;    
        }
        if ( timeout[portNum] >= MAX_TIMEOUT )
        {
          retVal = FALSE;
          break;
        }
        timeout[portNum]++;
      }
      return( retVal );
    }

    /*****************************************************************************
    ** Function name:       I2CStop
    **
    ** Descriptions:        Set the I2C stop condition, if the routine
    **              never exit, it's a fatal bus error.
    **
    ** parameters:          None
    ** Returned value:      true or never return
    ** 
    *****************************************************************************/
    uint32_t I2CStop( uint32_t portNum )
    {
      LPC_I2C[portNum]->CONSET = I2CONSET_STO;      /* Set Stop flag */ 
      LPC_I2C[portNum]->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;  /* Clear SI flag */ 

      /*--- Wait for STOP detected ---*/
      while( LPC_I2C[portNum]->CONSET & I2CONSET_STO );
      return TRUE;
    }

    /*****************************************************************************
    ** Function name:       I2CInit
    **
    ** Descriptions:        Initialize I2C controller as a master
    **
    ** parameters:          None
    ** Returned value:      None
    ** 
    *****************************************************************************/
    void I2C0Init( void ) 
    {
      LPC_SC->PCONP |= (1 << 7);

      /* set PIO0.27 and PIO0.28 to I2C0 SDA and SCL */
      /* function to 01 on both SDA and SCL. */
      LPC_PINCON->PINSEL1 &= ~((0x03<<22)|(0x03<<24));
      LPC_PINCON->PINSEL1 |= ((0x01<<22)|(0x01<<24));   

      /*--- Clear flags ---*/
      LPC_I2C0->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_AAC | I2CONCLR_SIC | I2CONCLR_STAC | I2CONCLR_I2ENC;    

      /*--- Reset registers ---*/
    #if FAST_MODE_PLUS
      LPC_PINCON->I2CPADCFG |= ((0x1<<0)|(0x1<<2));
      LPC_I2C0->SCLL   = I2SCLL_HS_SCLL;
      LPC_I2C0->SCLH   = I2SCLH_HS_SCLH;
    #else
      LPC_PINCON->I2CPADCFG &= ~((0x1<<0)|(0x1<<2));
      LPC_I2C0->SCLL   = I2SCLL_SCLL;
      LPC_I2C0->SCLH   = I2SCLH_SCLH;
    #endif

      /* Install interrupt handler */
      NVIC_EnableIRQ(I2C0_IRQn);

      LPC_I2C0->CONSET = I2CONSET_I2EN;
      return;
    }

    /*****************************************************************************
    ** Function name:       I2C1Init
    **
    ** Descriptions:        Initialize I2C controller as a master
    **
    ** parameters:          None
    ** Returned value:      None
    ** 
    *****************************************************************************/
    void I2C1Init( void ) 
    {
      LPC_SC->PCONP |= (1 << 19);

    #if 0
      /* set PIO0.0 and PIO0.1 to I2C1 SDA and SCL */
      /* function to 11 on both SDA and SCL. */
      LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 &= ~((0x3<<0)|(0x3<<2));
      LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= ((0x3<<0)|(0x3<<2));
      LPC_PINCON->PINMODE0 &= ~((0x3<<0)|(0x3<<2));
      LPC_PINCON->PINMODE0 |= ((0x2<<0)|(0x2<<2));      /* No pull-up no pull-down */
      LPC_PINCON->PINMODE_OD0 |= ((0x01<<0)|(0x1<<1));  /* Open drain */    
    #endif
    #if 1
      /* set PIO0.19 and PIO0.20 to I2C1 SDA and SCL */
      /* function to 11 on both SDA and SCL. */
      LPC_PINCON->PINSEL1 &= ~((0x3<<6)|(0x3<<8));
      LPC_PINCON->PINSEL1 |= ((0x3<<6)|(0x3<<8));
      LPC_PINCON->PINMODE1 &= ~((0x3<<6)|(0x3<<8));
      LPC_PINCON->PINMODE1 |= ((0x2<<6)|(0x2<<8));  /* No pull-up no pull-down */
      LPC_PINCON->PINMODE_OD0 |= ((0x1<<19)|(0x1<<20)); 
    #endif

      /*--- Clear flags ---*/
      LPC_I2C1->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_AAC | I2CONCLR_SIC | I2CONCLR_STAC | I2CONCLR_I2ENC;    

      /*--- Reset registers ---*/
      LPC_I2C1->SCLL   = I2SCLL_SCLL;
      LPC_I2C1->SCLH   = I2SCLH_SCLH;

      /* Install interrupt handler */
      NVIC_EnableIRQ(I2C1_IRQn);

      LPC_I2C1->CONSET = I2CONSET_I2EN;
      return;
    }

    /*****************************************************************************
    ** Function name:       I2C2Init
    **
    ** Descriptions:        Initialize I2C controller as a master
    **
    ** parameters:          None
    ** Returned value:      None
    ** 
    *****************************************************************************/
    void I2C2Init( void ) 
    {
      LPC_SC->PCONP |= (1 << 26);

      /* set PIO0.10 and PIO0.11 to I2C2 SDA and SCL */
      /* function to 10 on both SDA and SCL. */
      LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 &= ~((0x03<<20)|(0x03<<22));
      LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= ((0x02<<20)|(0x02<<22));
      LPC_PINCON->PINMODE0 &= ~((0x03<<20)|(0x03<<22));
      LPC_PINCON->PINMODE0 |= ((0x02<<20)|(0x2<<22));   /* No pull-up no pull-down */
      LPC_PINCON->PINMODE_OD0 |= ((0x01<<10)|(0x1<<11));    

      /*--- Clear flags ---*/
      LPC_I2C2->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_AAC | I2CONCLR_SIC | I2CONCLR_STAC | I2CONCLR_I2ENC;    

      /*--- Reset registers ---*/
      LPC_I2C2->SCLL   = I2SCLL_SCLL;
      LPC_I2C2->SCLH   = I2SCLH_SCLH;

      /* Install interrupt handler */
      NVIC_EnableIRQ(I2C2_IRQn);

      LPC_I2C2->CONSET = I2CONSET_I2EN;
      return;
    }

    /*****************************************************************************
    ** Function name:       I2CEngine
    **
    ** Descriptions:        The routine to complete a I2C transaction
    **                      from start to stop. All the intermitten
    **                      steps are handled in the interrupt handler.
    **                      Before this routine is called, the read
    **                      length, write length, I2C master buffer,
    **                      and I2C command fields need to be filled.
    **                      see i2cmst.c for more details. 
    **
    ** parameters:          I2C port number
    ** Returned value:      master state of current I2C port.
    ** 
    *****************************************************************************/
    uint32_t I2CEngine( uint32_t portNum ) 
    {
      /*--- Issue a start condition ---*/
      LPC_I2C[portNum]->CONSET = I2CONSET_STA;  /* Set Start flag */

      I2CMasterState[portNum] = I2C_BUSY;   

      while ( I2CMasterState[portNum] == I2C_BUSY )
      {
        if ( timeout[portNum] >= MAX_TIMEOUT )
        {
          I2CMasterState[portNum] = I2C_TIME_OUT;
          break;
        }
        timeout[portNum]++;
      }
      LPC_I2C[portNum]->CONCLR = I2CONCLR_STAC;

      return ( I2CMasterState[portNum] );
    }

    /******************************************************************************
    **                            End Of File
    ******************************************************************************/
```

MPU6050 functions

```
    void mpu6050BurstRead(uint8_t startRegAdd, uint8_t length, uint8_t *data) {
        // Clear buffers
        uint32_t i;
        for (i = 0; i < BUFSIZE; i++) {
            I2CMasterBuffer[I2C_PORT][i] = 0x00;
            I2CSlaveBuffer[I2C_PORT][i] = 0x00;
        }

        I2CWriteLength[I2C_PORT] = 2;
        I2CReadLength[I2C_PORT] = 0;
        I2CMasterBuffer[I2C_PORT][0] = MPU6050_ADDRESS;
        I2CMasterBuffer[I2C_PORT][1] = startRegAdd;
        I2CEngine(I2C_PORT);

        for (i = 0; i < BUFSIZE; i++) {
            I2CMasterBuffer[I2C_PORT][i] = 0x00;
            I2CSlaveBuffer[I2C_PORT][i] = 0x00;
        }

        I2CWriteLength[I2C_PORT] = 1;
        I2CReadLength[I2C_PORT] = length;
        I2CMasterBuffer[I2C_PORT][0] = MPU6050_ADDRESS|MPU6050_READ;
        I2CEngine(I2C_PORT);

        memcpy(data,I2CSlaveBuffer,length);

    }

    void mpu6050Write(uint8_t regAdd,uint8_t regValue) {
        // Clear buffers
        uint32_t i;
        for (i = 0; i < BUFSIZE; i++) {
            I2CMasterBuffer[I2C_PORT][i] = 0x00;
            I2CSlaveBuffer[I2C_PORT][i] = 0x00;
        }

        I2CWriteLength[I2C_PORT] = 3;
        I2CReadLength[I2C_PORT] = 0;
        I2CMasterBuffer[I2C_PORT][0] = MPU6050_ADDRESS;
        I2CMasterBuffer[I2C_PORT][1] = regAdd;
        I2CMasterBuffer[I2C_PORT][2] = regValue;
        I2CEngine(I2C_PORT);
    }
```

Comment: What?  We have no hardware, no debugger, no scope, no environment, no code. Also, 'I tried with many possible ways' - what ways?  You've done some debugging but will not tell us what you did?  You may be lucky and someone who has encountered this problem before will come up with an answer, but apart from that, we can't help much with the scant info you have presented.

Comment: Sorry Martin James.., I've edit that post. Plz look at once

Answer (score 3):

Finally I fixed the issue.

I make the variable(RdIndex0) zero in the ISR I2C0_IRQHandler(). Then it started working.

Following correction i made.

```
void I2C0_IRQHandler(void) 
{
  ............

  ............

  switch ( StatValue )
  {
    case 0x08:          /* A Start condition is issued. */
    ...........
    RdIndex0 = 0;     // Added this line
    ...............................
    ...............................
    break;
```